# tight recv loop for non blocked socket

Tags: c++, sockets, loops

I'm currently programming a server using winsock2 which max. workload will be around 1000 concurrent connections. For accepting sockets I'm using a seperated thread that runs accept() in blocking mode. But for receiving data I thought about (also having a seperated thread), but this time using a non-blocking mode and code like this pseudo:

```
for (;;)
{
    foreach socket
    {
        int num = socket.recv(..);

        if (num == SOCKET_ERROR && WSAGetLastError() == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK)
            continue;
        else
            // push buffer to worker thread / handle error
    }
    thread.sleep(1);
}
```

Would this work without giving the cpu a hard time?
The two main reasons I found in the internet about why this is bad code are 1. cpu load 2. many kernel calls. The sleep solves the first problem (I hope) but I don't know anything about the call performance of receive in non blocking socket mode nor why many of those calls are making this a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work without giving the CPU a hard time. The sleep is literally a waste of time when you could be blocking for exactly the correct length of time.

Don't do this. I can't imagine why you would even think of it inthe first place.